# problem with uploading file in curl method of php

Tags: php, file, curl

The problem is I have two php files in my local host. In one I send a file and in another I get it. The code that sends is below:

```
$ch=curl_init('localhost/hach.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
    'certificate'=>'@'.realpath('certificate.pem')
    ));

$dh=curl_exec($ch);
echo ($dh);
curl_close($ch);
```

and in hach.php I have:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

but the showing result in the line  echo ($dh) shows me array() alone without any info of file that was sent.
and my file was located in same file as sender.php and hach.php.
Where should I correct my code?

Comment: remove the () from around $dh, just do `echo $dh;` or even `var_dump($dh);`

Comment: I do both things you say but it doesn't affect.the result was same as before.